# Oracle 19C: How to get execution plan for entire Stored Procedure?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, performance-testing

We have a SP and it has around 12 updates with multiple joins and it is noticed that the performance is slow. Is there any way to generate execution plan for entire SP instead of examining each statements?

Comment: PL/SQL Profiler and sql trace 10046 (+tkprof) are the first things you need to start with. They are pretty simple

Comment: Are they both available in SQL Developer tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (in SQL Developer, SQLcl or SQL*Plus)

```
begin
  dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable(waits=>true);
  my_problem_proc;
  dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable;
end;
```

V$DIAG_INFO will give you the name of the trace file (or speak to your DBA) and you can work from there.